# balance() method doesn't work when called in python

Tags: python, class, methods

I have a BankAccount class that allows a balance to be set, an amount to be deposited/withdrawn, and then a method that returns the balance.

```
class BankAccount():

    def __init__(self, initialBalance = 0):
        self.balance = initialBalance 

    def __repr__(self):
        return("BankAccount({})".format(self.balance))

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount

    def balance(self):
        return(self.balance())
```

But when I call the balance method `(b.balance())`, it get a float object not callable error. But if I call it `b.balance` it returns the proper amount. I'm confused on what the error means and why the method call doesn't work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have an instance method called balance, and an instance attribute with the same name balance? You are asking for trouble doing that. I strongly suggest renaming one of them.

Comment: Decide whether ``balance`` is a method or property. You are overwriting the defined method with the value supplied to your ctor.

Comment: @idjaw thank you! I didn't know that the names conflicted... Live and you learn.

Comment: @Frank Take a look at the upvoted answers, especially that posted by TigerhawkT3. It will give you a pretty solid explanation of what is going on. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work to have an attribute and a method with the same name. You can either give the attribute a different name:

```
class BankAccount():

    def __init__(self, initialBalance = 0):
        self._balance = initialBalance 

    def __repr__(self):
        return("BankAccount({})".format(self._balance))

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self._balance += amount

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self._balance -= amount

    def balance(self):
        return(self._balance)

print(BankAccount())
```

or access the attribute directly (and remove the accessor method):

```
class BankAccount():

    def __init__(self, initialBalance = 0):
        self.balance = initialBalance 

    def __repr__(self):
        return("BankAccount({})".format(self.balance))

    def __repr__(self):
        return("BankAccount({})".format(self.balance))

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount

print(BankAccount())
```

Comment: Oh! I wasn't aware of that... Thank you that makes sense

Answer (score 3):

When you define a class, all of its methods are defined, but not called. This includes `def balance(self):`. Those methods are accessible via references e.g. `self.methodname`. When you create an instance of this class, it calls the `__init__` method, defined as `def __init__(self, initialBalance=0):`. This method assigns an instance attribute `self.balance` and gives it a floating-point value. When you do that, the old instance attribute that `self.balance` used to point to - the method you defined - is no longer referred to, so it's collected by Python's garbage collector and disappears.

The key is that Python does not have one bag for function names and another bag for other names. It simply has a bag for all instance attribute names, whether they point to a floating-point number, a function, or something else.

Also, if you hadn't overwritten `self.balance`, that method would've been even more problematic, as it calls itself (recursion) with no way of stopping. So, when you call it, it will call itself, which will then call itself, forever, producing an error.

Simply remove the defined `def balance(self):` method entirely. It doesn't look like it was doing anything useful, and you can simply access the `self.balance` attribute directly.

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
def balance(self)
```

it is an attribute.  If you have an attribute, you don't need a method to retrieve it

Comment: That doesn't explain anything.

Answer (score 0):

`self.balance()` calls the balance method of the BankAccount class and `b.balance` is the balance attribute of the BankAccount object.

Since return is not a method you cannot do return(something) and that's why you are getting an error saying `self.balance()` which is a float is not callable. But when you do `b.balance` it is a perfectly valid syntax and it returns the value of balance attribute which is the current balance.

Suggestion: Have different names for attribute balance and method balance(probably check_balance).